# Intersect sorts out the results alphabetically c#

Tags: c#, intersect

Alright so this is my first question here at stack. So i have the current code (Note im using c#)-

```
   public static void ReadSuburbs()
        {
            String directory = @"C:\Address Sorting\";
            String[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "FileA-Database.txt"));
            String[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Suburbs.txt"));

            IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesB.Intersect(linesA);

            File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "ResultsSuburbs.txt"), onlyB);
        }
```

What im trying to do is get all the suburbs from database a and print them exactly as they were in the text file. So ill just give you a example of a result i was looking to get.

Lets say my database a contained the street names

```
12 margret st kallangur

14 simpson st zillmere

43 pauls rd bowen hills
```

And the suburbs.txt contains a list of all suburbs in australia

The result im looking for would be

```
kallangur

zillmere

bowen hills
```

But what im getting is

```
Bowen HIlls
Kallangur
Zillmere
```

Is there another method i can use except intersect to get the result im looking for?

EDIT : So basically what i have is a database full of addresses that have been inputted incorrectly - So basically we have **12 saint street Kallangur** and many other addresses in this database and what i need to do is seperate the suburbs from the street names.

Comment: I don't see how you are getting any output at all, since `12 margret st kallangur` and from the other file just `kallangur` are not the same string. In your example, not a single line from FileA-Database.txt matches a single line from Suburbs.txt exactly.

Comment: .Intersect() should not change the order `the marked elements are yielded in the order in which they were collected.` see the Remarks section https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Are the suburbs in Suburbs.txt alphabetically sorted? That might be the case.

Comment: Yeah they dont match exactly, but i have been getting output, is there a different method i should use? And Rahul yeah they are alphabetically sorted, took me a while to gather all the suburbs in australia and i sorted it alphabetically.

Comment: Then as @nineberry said, the order is determined by your sorted list. Change your intersect query per his recommendation

Comment: We'd still need a bit more details. Your task might not be so easy to solve because there are actually valid road names containing suburb names.

Comment: Not sure what other details to give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesB.Intersect(linesA);
```

the contents of linesB define the order of the resulting sequence. If you want linesA to define the order, just turn the statement around and use

```
IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesA.Intersect(linesB);
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem :) Also i understand what i did wrong. Haha woops

Comment: You should be aware that if you have multiple addresses in the same suburb, you will only get one entry in the resulting sequence per suburb!

Comment: Ahh just realised that just then when i was going through the file, rather not be spoon fed so, can i have a hint to fix that?

Comment: It is difficult to know what you are actually trying to achieve. Edit your question and explain a bit more detailled what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Edited  - EDIT : So basically what i have is a database full of addresses that have been inputted incorrectly - So basically we have **12 saint street Kallangur** and many other addresses in this database and what i need to do is seperate the suburbs from the street names.

Comment: Edit again, just used the where function instead, now produces duplicates aswell :)